# PostgreSQL: does the order of rows in a bulk insert control the order of `FOR EACH ROW` triggers?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, deadlock, bulk-insert, upsert

I have a trigger like `BEFORE INSERT ON table_a FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION upsert_into_table_b()`.

If I execute a bulk insert like `INSERT INTO table_a ([columns]) VALUES ([row 1 values]), ([row 2 values])...`, will the trigger run sequentially on the `table_a` rows in the order they were stated? In other words, will the upsert into `table_b` be done for row 1, then for row 2, in the order they were given in `VALUES`?

(I ask because, if so, reordering the `VALUES` may help me solve a deadlock on the upsert.)

Comment: It sure seems like it - the upsert uses `ON CONFLICT (column_a, column_b)` and ordering the values in the query by `column_a, column_b` seems to fix the deadlock on the upsert. And if I remove the trigger entirely and do the upserts manually in an inconsistent order in two concurrent transactions in separate `psql` sessions, I can cause the deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL calls the trigger functions in the order in which the rows are inserted. In your case, this happens to be the order in which you write them in the `VALUES` statement.

But that's only an implementation detail, and you cannot rely on it. Future versions of PostgreSQL are free to change that, for example by reordering the rows in the `VALUE` statement to optimize the `INSERT`. There is no such change planned, but you had better verify the behavior before each major upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and warning. My specific use case is: bulk insert incoming `sensor, metric` values (eg 'sensor 5, temperature') and upsert into a table that tracks the most recent value for each combo (eg, 'most recent temp for sensor 5'). I got deadlocks when concurrent bulk inserts triggered upserts for the same combos in opposite orders. Any ideas on how to do the upsert without deadlocks or relying on this implementation detail?

Comment: You could use `COPY`. Other than that, there is the slow solution of looping and inserting rows one by one.

Comment: Seems like another possible solution is a per-statement trigger with a "transition table" - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-AUDIT-TRANSITION-EXAMPLE
But that won't work for us because the the table is a TimescaleDB hypertable and it doesn't support it.
If I have to switch solutions, I think I'll use a recurring background job to do upserts based on the new rows since the last time the job ran.